# SSIS runs in kind of infinite loop

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have encountered a problem and found no solution in the internet.
We created an SSIS package that reads from a flat (CSV) file, does some manipulation and then creates accounts in a customer CRM Dynamics 365 (online) system. The manipulations are minimal we just use two option sets elements to transfer input into the respective option sets inside Dynamics CRM.

All works perfectly fine, but the tool keeps creating accounts in some kind of infinite loop, so it starts all over again after he is done with my CSV list.

here is what my flow looks like:
[image]

We have a simple CSV file that reads in the data, then we add a static column with "derived column" (to avoid any kind of scripting - as we thought there the infinite loop might come from) to add our UserIDType= "systemuser",.. then we do two simple options set mapping, and then create the accounts...

As described all works fine, except the stuff runs forever until the CRM server times out.
There are no plugins etc. on the CRM system etc. its purely our dataflow that causes this strange thing,.. any ideas?

Any help would be very much appreciated as we searched for hours now why this happens...

Answer (score 0):

Okay we solved it,.. I keep this question up as other people might run into this crazy problem. Using SSIS there seems to be a bug, when you do not have many records (below the batchsize). Then it runs into circles. Reduce Batchsize to 1 and problem is gone.